# Is it worth using distinct() with collect(toSet())

Tags: java, java-stream

When collecting the elements of a stream into a set, is there any advantage (or drawback) to also specifying `.distinct()` on the stream? For example:

```
return items.stream().map(...).distinct().collect(toSet());
```

Given that the set will already remove duplicates, this seems redundant, but does it offer any performance advantage or disadvantage? Does the answer depend on whether the stream is parallel/sequential or ordered/unordered?

Comment: It is not redundant. distinct() will preserve the first occurrence while collect(toSet()) will preserve the last one. Both have unstable results if executed on an unordered stream.

Comment: @Alexander You have a reference for that? I just tried with a stream of Strings (using `new` to create two equal but not same strings), and in both cases, it was the first string that was preserved.

Comment: I refered to the JavaDoc of distinct() with states that distinct preservers the first in order of occurence. But you are right, it makes no difference with my simple test cases. I have not tried yet if the result changes using a parallel stream.

Comment: @Alexander the result is not surprising, since Sets retain the old value if you try to add a duplicate.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--), `distinct` is a stateful intermediate operation.

If you literally have `.distinct` followed immediately by `.collect`, it doesn't really add any benefit.  Maybe if the `.distinct` implementation is more performant than the `Set` duplication check, you might get some benefit, but if you're collecting to a set you're going to end up with the same result anyway.

If, on the other hand, `.distinct` occurs before your `.map` operation, and that particular mapping is an expensive operation, you may get some gains there because you're processing less data overall.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately the items aren't distinct before the map stage.

Comment: `distinct` is no magic. It basically fills a `HashSet` (or `LinkedHashSet` when ordered) internally. If there was a way to make this more efficient, i.e. using some optimized internal class, the `toSet()` collector, sitting in the same package, would use it as well…

Comment: I'm accepting this answer as it gets to the important point, IMO: the benefit of `distinct()` is when it occurs at an intermediate point in the pipeline, to reduce the amount of data sent to downstream tasks. If it occurs as the penultimate step before a `collect(..)` to a set then it does not add anything. You could also use it to de-duplicate a stream and then collect into a non-Set class (e.g. a List) if that is what you required for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

While you have the same result, they don't do the same thing: `toSet()` use `HashSet`, and you lose the initial ordering which is what distinct can preserve if required:

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#distinct--):

> Preserving stability for distinct() in parallel pipelines is
>   relatively expensive (requires that the operation act as a full
>   barrier, with substantial buffering overhead), and stability is often
>   not needed. Using an unordered stream source (such as
>   generate(Supplier)) or removing the ordering constraint with
>   BaseStream.unordered() may result in significantly more efficient
>   execution for distinct() in parallel pipelines, if the semantics of
>   your situation permit. If consistency with encounter order is
>   required, and you are experiencing poor performance or memory
>   utilization with distinct() in parallel pipelines, switching to
>   sequential execution with BaseStream.sequential() may improve
>   performance.

If you require stability, then it is `distinct()`. Using `toSet()` after would be useless (if not required by an API).

That is however useful if you have an `equals` implementing a partial equality:

```
class F {
  int a;
  int b;
  @Override int hashCode() {return Objects.hashCode(a);}
  @Override boolean equals(Object other) {
    if (other == this) return true;
    if (!(other instanceof F)) return false;
    return a == ((F)other).a;
  }
}
```

If you have `a = F(10, 1)` and `b = F(10, 2)` they are equals. But not all their fields are equals.

If in the list you have `(b, a)`

- With `toSet()` you won't always have this order. You might have (b, a), etc.
- With distinct() you preserve this information, eg: `(b, a)`.

This however assume some prerequisites (sequential, etc).

**Note:** this could be done using a `TreeSet` and appropriate `compareTo` method.

Comment: Since `a` and `b` are treated as equal, the result would be just the first element, i.e. `b`, wouldn't it?

Comment: Wouldn't using `toCollection(LinkedHashSet::new)` preserve the order too?

Comment: Not guaranteed. If you have a parallel stream, it may (I don't know if Java does it) split the list into 2 distinct sublist, then apply it in its own thread. eg: the collector using `LinkedHashSet::add` won't know if the item passed to it is the first (b) or the second (a). It may be true if the Stream does not need to do "extra work" (split the list, etc)..

Answer (score 0):

distinct will call equals/hashcode to separate items and later toSet will do the same thing (even if after distinct there is no need, but toSet can't really know that), so basically you are just duplicating the calls. It should performance slightly worse IMO. It is pretty easy to measure too.